# short code to determine pdf page count and pdf page size for upload to woocommerce site

Tags: pdf, printing, upload, wordpress, code

I am looking for short code or a woocommerce solution to determine the page size and page count of a pdf document for upload. Customers can upload pdf files to my woocommerce website, and I would like to be able to determine the page size and page count of the document at the time of upload. To see a better example of what I am talking about here are 2 webistes that use what I am looking for:

https://thefoldline.com/product/copy-shop-printing-upload-any-pattern/

or

https://pdfplotting.com/product/pattern-printing-bnw/

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin that they're using is created by this company:
https://webtoprintshop.com/

if you want access to the plugin I recommend you reach out to that company directly